# Spatial Reference not matching between feature class and dataset. Cannot import feature class into dataset

Tags: arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I will preface this by saying I am aware of a workaround that involves creating a new GDB and then using the "Feature Class to Geodatabase Tool" and moving everything around there. I am using the latest version of ArcGIS Pro.  Regardless, I cannot understand why, in my existing geodatabase, I am unable to create a dataset and then move my feature classes there.

In my existing GDB there are no datasets or organization. When I open the GDB it is just a long list of feature classes in the same coordinate system. To better organize this geodatabase I create a dataset, set the projection to the same one as all the feature classes, and then try to drag feature classes into it. "Move Failed" The Spatial References Do Not Match"

That's fine, maybe there is some slight difference in the resolution or something. To account for this, I export one of my feature classes to a shapefile and save the .prj file. Now, I create another dataset within this GDB and manually input the .prj file for its coordinate system. Same error when I try to drag over the feature class whose .prj file I manually specified.

Is there something I could be missing here? I run into this issue quite often and it is frustrating that I do not have any real knowledge about how to fix it other than the workaround I mentioned at the beginning of this post.

If it matters, the projected coordinate system is: NAD 1983 StatePlane New York East FIPS 3101 (US Feet)

Comment: Please always specify the exact version of software in use, since the Answers to Questions are meant to last for a decade or more. You can't "drag-n-drop" feature classes that need reprojection as a copy operation; you need to [Project](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm) them. You should not *ever* use shapefile as an intermediary format in FGB feature class to FGDB feature class, because it will corrupt fields, datatypes, and geodatabase behavior.